# SystemVerilog Initialize multi dimensional parameterized array in

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, xilinx

I am trying to initialize a multi dimensional parameterized array in SystemVerilog which I have described as below:

```
...
parameter INPUT_WIDTH = 16;
parameter NUM_ELEMENTS = 4;
...
reg signed [INPUT_WIDTH-1 : 0 ] ss_res_reg[NUM_ELEMENTS-1:0];
```

I want to initialize the `ss_res_reg` to zero on every falling edge of `rst` so:

```
always_ff @(posedge clk or negedge rst) begin
    if(~rst) begin
        ss_res_reg <= '{NUM_ELEMENTS{NUM_ELEMENTS{1'b0}}};
    end else begin
        ss_res_reg <= ss_res;
    end
end
```

The problem is with this line `ss_res_reg <= '{NUM_ELEMENTS{INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}}};`. If I change it to `ss_res_reg <= '{NUM_ELEMENTS{16'b0}};` it works perfectly fine. However, when I want to use the `INPUT_WIDTH` parameter, Xilinx tool gives me the following error: `syntax error near {`. I also tried `ss_res_reg <= '{NUM_ELEMENTS{16{1'b0}}};` and got the same error. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error lies in the fact that you can not replicate unpacked array elements.

There is a simple solution:

```
if(~rst) 
   for (integer i=0; i<NUM_ELEMENTS; i++)
      ss_res_reg[i] <=  {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `default` label in an assignment pattern to assign all elements of an unpacked array having any number of dimensions:

```
always_ff @(posedge clk or negedge rst) begin
    if(~rst) begin
        ss_res_reg <= '{default:'0};
    end else begin
        ss_res_reg <= ss_res;
    end
end
```

`'0` means fill the packed array with 0's